# APK isn't installed even though I use generated Signed APK

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I think there's some update for blocking the installation of APK from outside. Normally, I used to install apks with generated signed apk. But, recently It doesn't work at all. I deleted the app properly, So, it has no issue with the previous app. Everything is checked and filled up.

Is there is changes with Android OS?

Comment: This is just a guess but if you have multi user enabled delete the app from all the users too.

Comment: @NaveenNiraula multi users? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I was using demo app provided by third party company.

And the problem was an attribute of `manafiests.xml`

It was like this:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

And the solution was deletng `testOnly` attribute of application tag like this:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

What `testOnly` does is when it's enabled it can only be installed by `adb` and not able to publish on Google Play.

So, it was not Android OS version problem.

For more information: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element